# Do I need to have domain/entity class if all of my business logic is in the service class?

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices

I'm working on a REST API application that does not have a persistence layer. I receive a request, do some transformation logic and return the response.

- **Do I still need a domain/entity layer between my view dto and the business logic service class?**
- **If so, what's the advantage of adding a domain layer?**
- **Should I use Mapstruct to handle complex mapping logic to replace a part of the transformation logic?**

Comment: either way having domain model always makes easy and clean `abstraction, logic`

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit about the clean abstraction?

Answer (score 2):

Do I still need a domain/entity layer between my view dto and the business logic service class?

> Don't have entity, entity meant for persistence have normal domain class, and DTO class which is actually meant for Data transfer ie requets/resposne, Domain is meant for some business layer logic , in DTO we can put only the request / response , but if there is a logic for processing that request and have one domain to object model to do the business process

If so, what's the advantage of adding a domain layer?

> Domain Objects (DO) (and the classes from which they are derived) implement business logic, as such they are only located in the Business logic layer / Domain (the essential meaning is the same even if the terms are different).

Should I use Mapstruct to handle complex mapping logic to replace a part of the transformation logic?

> We can use the ModelMapper to convert from domain object to any other same object or there is Dozzer Mapper also we can use that library

```
Request DTO ->Controller Layer --> Service Layer --Uses business logic --> Domain Object --Convert to Response DTO --> Response DTO
```

Answer (score 0):

Its good design if application is having View Layer, Business Layer and Backend layer. We don't have to use Entities as POJO, instead we must have the separate utility classes for transforming the Entity data to Models and Models to Entities. That will segregate your business layer from Data layer. If you are making any changes in entities that will not at all impact your business layer and vice versa.

Hope that will clarify the understanding.